# How to import generated package from a maven module in another maven module?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

For context, I have a maven project that contains 2 modules, so 3 poms files, one for the parent and the other two of the childs .My issue is about creating a jar for the second module that uses classes generated by the first module. The first module is using openAPI to generate classes from a yaml that are used in the second module which is a spring boot application.

When I execute `mvn clean install`, on my entire project, or on the second module, it says that it cannot find symbol, the symbol being a class generated by the first module. When i try to run by Spring Boot, it works correctly, creates the jar and executes. This is the pom of the parent project and this is how i defined the module order(I saw that it is important to specify each module is compiled first).

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>api-generation</module>
        <module>stock-keeping-logic</module>

    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
 
</project>
```

And this is the dependency in the second module

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pss.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-generation</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And this is the plugin I used for the first module to generate the classes:

```
     <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>spring-boot-api</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static/api-docs.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
                                <useSpringController>true</useSpringController>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <apiPackage>com.api.generation</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.api.generation.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.api.generation.handler</invokerPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
           
        </plugins>
```

I looked over google for solve but I couldn't find anything to work.

Comment: If use spring boot and JDK8+ you should not generate code with joda time anymore, furthermore the module which uses openapi generator will generate code and package that which can simply being used as a dependency in an other module... Also the question is where you have defined the openapi-generator-maven-plugin? In pluginManagement? if so that's wrong ...and never generate into `src/main/java` ... remove that configuration... it's gernating into `target/generated-sources`... etc. that's the correct way...

Answer (score 1):

If you use `spring-boot-starter-parent`, you create spring boot JARs, not libraries. Spring boot JARs do not work as dependencies out of the box.